# Is there a specific protocol to add everything to Git using Rugged?

Tags: ruby, git, libgit2, rugged

I recently began using Rugged, and have already run into some problems. Basically all I want to do is add everything in a Git repo, commit the staged changes, and push everything to a branch. I've started out with the first step as follows:

```
@repo = Rugged::Repository.new(Dir.pwd)
@index = @repo.index

def git_add
    @index.add mode: 'add-all'
end
```

But the console ends up screaming at me. I browsed through libgit2's documentation, and couldn't find any examples of adding everything in repo. Some thorough Googling yielded similar results. I could probably have just jammed in a `@repo.workdir.entries` as the `path` parameter for `index.add`, but I'm not sure. Is there a better way to go about this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Depending on whether you want to stage every file or just the ones which are already in, you have two options, `Index#add_all` and `Index#update_all` respectively.

You can use `repo.index.add_all()` to stage every file under the specified directory. You can use `repo.index.update_all()` to do the same but only for those files which are already known to the repository, similarly to git's `-A` and `-u` options.